# multiple keys for one value dictionary using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, dictionary

multiple keys for one value in c# dictionary.I want to form one dictionary i tried with this code for form dictionary

```
 var dictionary = e.Args.Select(a => a.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2))
                    .GroupBy(a => a[0], a => a.Length == 2 ? a[1] : null)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Then how can i form dictionary that have multiple key for one value using c#.

Comment: I wrote an answer for C# 7.0 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829428/531524

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) (.NET 3.5 and above) from MSDN

> Lookup(Of TKey, TElement)
>
> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

By the way, if all your keys are contiguous (ie 1, 2, 3, ...), use a simple array.

---

[Referred from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717006/how-to-optimize-a-dictionary-with-multiple-keys-per-distinct-value)   and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10935485/2218635)

Comment: If am correct then Lookup is other way around, it consists of unique key with number of values.